# Expand List Operation

Tags: list-manipulation

On applying a multiplication and subtraction on a list, like so:

```
x = 2y - 4;
```

Where y is a list containing fractions of complex numbers generated from dynamic input, instead of getting a new list with that operation applied to each element of the list, instead the output is simplified, in the form:

```
-4 + 2{element1, element2, element3, etc}
```

This means I can't then apply normal list functions to x. How can I convert this style of input into just one list:

```
{-4 + element1, -4 + element2, -4 + element3}
```

When I make y non-dynamic, it formats it correctly, so that seems to be part of the issue.

My exact code is this:

```
mirror[v_] := v^2
a = 3;
b = 4;
{Slider2D[Dynamic[{a, b}], {{-10, 0}, {10, 100}, 1}], Dynamic[{a, b}]}

y = Dynamic[Replace[t, Solve[-1/D[mirror[t], t] == (mirror[t] - b)/(t - a), t]]];
x = 2 y - a
```

Comment: You do have a space (for multiplication) between 2 and y, right ?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference either way.

Comment: Try making the multiplication explicit: x=2*y-4

Comment: @Varkor Maybe the issue is with the usage of `Dynamic`; could you post a more detailed example of your actual code ?

Comment: I think Dynamic is the issue. I've edited my post with the code I've used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The head of `y` in your setup is `Dynamic` not `List`.  That is why `Plus` and `Times` will not operate as you expected -- `y` is not a `List`.  Perhaps this will have the behavior you seek:

```
mirror[v_] := v^2
a = 3;
b = 4;
{Slider2D[Dynamic[{a, b}], {{-10, 0}, {10, 100}, 1}], Dynamic[{a, b}]}

y := Replace[t, Solve[-1/D[mirror[t], t] == (mirror[t] - b)/(t - a), t]];
Dynamic[x = 2 y - a]
```

The general rule of thumb is to put `Dynamic` around what is to be displayed, not around component variables or expressions.  (It is more complicated than this, of course, but most times, `var = Dynamic[..]` will not be the thing to do.)

Note also the use of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) in the assignment for `y`.  This makes `y` represent a formula that is evaluated only when `Dynamic[x = 2 y - a]` is updated.

Comment: Thank you! I was using `Dynamic` when I should have been using `SetDelayed` – it makes much more sense now!